# Derby is running only using embedded driver

Tags: java, spring-boot, derby, jdbctemplate

I am trying to connect to running Derby database from spring boot application but every time when I start my app, I can see that embedded database is starting instead of connecting to existing one. I am pretty sure my Derby database is running since `java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyrun.jar server start` is executed without any error and I can connect from terminal to the database (using `ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/wrtschatz-db;'`).

I am autowiring jdbcTemplate

```
@Component
public class LessonItemsRetriever {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // methods doing jdbcTemplate.query(...) 
}
```

And I expect it to create datasource from my application.yml

```
spring.datasource:
    url: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/wortschatz-db
    username: ""
    password: ""
    driverClassName: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

But in fact, it's logging `2017-05-14 11:10:36.698  INFO 6418 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;create=true', username='sa'` which of course results `Schema 'SA' does not exist; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist` when I try to execute my queries.

What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got back to my project and what I can say is that used wrong dependency. I used embedded derby while I need a client to connect to external derby db. In my build.gradle correct dependency is:

```
compile("org.apache.derby:derbyclient:10.13.1.1")
```